# RegisterNatives failed for 'android/webkit/BrowserFrame'

Tags: java, android, logcat, dalvik

Building a ROM from source, but stuck at a point. I have understood the error but have no idea exactly what should the fix be.
ROM stucks on boot and I see this

```
E/dalvikvm(  353): ERROR: couldn't find native method

E/dalvikvm(  353): Requested: Landroid/webkit/BrowserFrame;.nativeAddJavascriptInterface:(ILjava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;)V

E/dalvikvm(  353): Candidate: Landroid/webkit/BrowserFrame;.nativeAddJavascriptInterface:(ILjava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;Z)V

E/JNIHelp (  353): RegisterNatives failed for 'android/webkit/BrowserFrame', aborting
```

From the error, what is requested in that method is `(ILjava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;)V` but what being provided is `(ILjava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;Z)V`
Difference lies in that `Z`

Can anyone think of a solution for that method in BrowserFrame.java ? or any other workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The additional argument was added late last year, in a pair of changes:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/94740e6c333a109be7516abbd17dd418f23b4f0c

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/webkit/+/f2d8c5bed31609d7d6e3ae77f33e90ea7f888eb3

It sounds like you have the change from frameworks/base, but not the corresponding change from external/webkit.

Comment: Ah! I didn't knew this :D Thanks for this. I will merge the changes in the webkit!